# Is concept of directional derivative is different to people with different cultures?

Tags: partial-derivative

When I studied math in my university Bauman Moscow State Techinical University we used notion of directional derivative as a quantity which can be evaluated **even for function which has one side derivative** but is not differetiable.
[1], p.142

But looks that people from other cultures refer to directional derivative as two side derivative where *h* or *t* can come to zero from left or right:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectionalDerivative.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative

So in fact the concept that I used is only differ from the definition provided is that I and other Russian people consider t or h->+0.

For some maybe historical reasons - english speaking world refer to directional derivative as characterstic how function change in both v and -v direction.

If so how should I refer to my case to change of the function only in direction **v** without touch **-v** at all?

**Refrences**

[1]Book written by http://www.mathnet.ru/php/person.phtml?personid=23029&option_lang=eng
V Канатников, Крищенко, и др. Дифференциальное исчисление функций многих переменных

Comment: I'm sure that your non-English text didn't use the term  "directional derivative" but a term in the language of the text which you translated as "directional derivative".

Comment: Non-english reference which I provided has term which I translated "directional derivative". But by direction it used something like a ray in function domain from in the points in which we consider, not a line. This is a difference. And very important difference if consider non smooth function

Comment: Looking around on Wikipedia, I think the concept of [semi-differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability#Higher-dimensional_case) seems to fit.

Comment: Thanks) So I will use this word when I will talk with my English speaking friends.

Comment: I have at hand a book of convex analysis (Hiriart-Urruty, Lemaréchal, *Convex Analysis and Minimization Algorithms 1*). In IV.4.2, the (French-speaking, I guess) authors and the translators needed to make the distinction between the two things you say. In a way, the solution they adopted is using "directional derivative" for $$\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+} \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}$$ and "partial derivative" for $$\lim\limits_{t\to 0} \frac{f(x+tv)-f(x)}{t}$$

Comment: Though, if wikipedia says it, you might be better sticking to semi-differentiability.